# How do I extend the vanity URL functionality within AEM

Tags: aem, vanity-url

I'm working in AEM 6.3. I'm trying to extend the default behavior of vanity URLs such that the following will happen:

1. User navigates to vanity URL and is redirected to actual URL
2. An ID that is associated (and authorable) is appended to the URL
3. Profit?

So I'd be extending the default page properties vanity functionality to include an ID.

Example:

```
Vanity URL: /foobar
ID: 123
Actual URL: www.test.com/plans
Resulting URL: www.test.com/plans?123
```

I've been able to modify the page properties to include a new field associated with the vanity URL in the UI. It doesn't appear to be saving the actual value though.

Haven't gotten to actually trying to apply this saved value to the URL through the dispatcher. How that would work is still very vague as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could do that. But you will have to build your page rendering logic based on the URL used for accessing the page. Guess you could manage with two public facing URLs - the vanity url and the final url constructed based on the ID.

As for dispatcher configuration, check the official documentation at the below link for handling vanity URLs 
https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html#enabling-access-to-vanity-urls-vanity-urls